# How to edit a date field in AG-GRID using typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, date, ag-grid-ng2

I am trying to make the ag-grid inline edit for a date. I could see an example using Jquery that has the ability to edit the date. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#many-editors-one-column
However, I want to use the typescript to make the date edit possible? Anyone has implemented this before?

Comment: try to implement it and if you get a problem post a [mcve] of the problem. As it is currently written, this question is too broad.